# Access an XML node by value

Tags: javascript, xml

Is it possible to access an XML section / node using an attribute value (e.g. `id`) using JavaScript?

For example:

```
<people>
    <person id='1'>
        <name>Tom</name>
        <age>30</age>
    </person>
    <person id='2'>
        <name>Ian</name>
        <age>22</age>
    </person>
    <person id='3'>
        <name>Ben</name>
        <age>45</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

I want to be able to select a person with a given id. For example, finding the ID 2 would return Ian.

This is possible in ActionScript like so:

```
xml.people.person.(@id == 2).name
```

Is something similar available in JS?

Comment: The same thing works in JavaScript if you have E4X, which only Firefox has. So on the off chance that you're developing a Firefox extension... :)

Comment: You may also want to look into jQuery.parseXML: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an `XMLDocument`, the only cross-browser way is to loop through the nodes:

```
var people = doc.getElementsByTagName('person');

for(var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
    if(people[i].getAttribute('id') === '2') {
        // Found it!
    }
}
```

If you need to do very complicated expressions, however, it may be worth it to use XPath, even though it needs a bit of cross-browser checking.

Here's the standard way:

```
document.evaluate('//person[@id='2']/text()[0]', doc.documentElement, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null).stringValue;
```

Comment: It's a bad way to search for element, especially if the xml document is big. And it's not the only way, browsers do support XPath.

Comment: @DonatasOlsevičius: I was in the process of adding XPath to my answer, but it's annoying in Internet Explorer, hence "the only cross-browser way".

Comment: w3schools say it works in IE too, you just have to add some more code for it - http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/tryit.asp?filename=try_xpath_select_cdnodes

However I cannot try it, I'm a Linux user.

Answer (score 1):

```
var xml_text="<people><person id='1'><name>Tom</name><age>30</age></person><person id='2'><name>Ian</name><age>22</age></person><person id='3'><name>Ben</name><age>45</age></person></people>";

var xmlParser = new DOMParser().parseFromString(xml_text, "text/xml").documentElement;

var person2Name = xmlParser.querySelector("people person[id='2'] name").textContent ​​;
```

[querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Document.querySelector) takes as input a string, which acts as a css selector on the node.

[textContent](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/prop_element_textcontent.asp) gets the text of a node.

IE8 doesnt support DOMParser: but you can use the following workaround

```
  xmlParser =new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
  xmlParser.async=false;
  xmlParser.loadXML(xml_text);
```

Comment: +1, this is much better than XPath. Annoying Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support either `DOMParser` or easy XPath, though, even though it does support `querySelector`...